# UI generation like OpenXava?

Tags: java, user-interface, grails, crud

Do you know any advanced UI generation framework that can generate UI from a model or database?

I know Grails and Spring Roo have something but they are only for simple CRUD operations, the best i found for now being OpenXava.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telosys Tools could be the right tool, it's a customizable code generator available as an Eclipse plugin. It uses the database schema as the model. We use it for CRUD screens with Spring MVC because the generated code is clean.
Some predefined bundles of templates are ready to use for Spring MVC, JPA, Angular JS, etc

See : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/

the tutorials are here : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

Comment: back then when i asked i did not know about telosys. i found later on a devoxx conference. indeed good beside minute project.!

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box Grails only generates a UI for CRUD operations, but the templates it uses to generate this UI are customisable, so with a bit of work, you can change them to generate whatever kind of UI you want.

There are a lot of plugins available that enhance and extend the default UI created.

Comment: Thanks...did not know that the generated uI is customizable ...will search for some of those plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at **[crud-rest-gen](https://github.com/yanndemel/crud-rest-gen)** project which explains how to use the **[crud-maven-plugin](https://github.com/yanndemel/crud-rest-gen/tree/master/crud-maven-plugin)** to generate :

- the CRUD Rest API
- the documentation of the API
- the HTML5/AngularJS CRUD Administration UI
- the Rest API for retrieving audit information and associated unit tests if you use Hibernate Envers to audit your entities

All you have to provide is the data model containing the JPA entities.

BTW the Telosys tool inspired me for developing the Web admin generation part :)